# Drop index postgres, what if duplicate index name exists

Tags: postgresql, indexing

below query works perfectly in postgre, because duplicate index within table is not allowed but with in DB it is allowed.

```
sandbox=# create schema test;
CREATE SCHEMA
sandbox=# create table public.a (a_id integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
sandbox=# create table test.a (a_id integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
sandbox=# create index a_idx on public.a (a_id);
CREATE INDEX
sandbox=# create index a_idx on test.a (a_id);
CREATE INDEX
```

**what happens when I do**

```
DROP INDEX a_idx;
```

1. will both the indexes get deleted ?
2. can I write `DROP INDEX test.a.a_idx` ?
3. how the index look up works while deleting ?

Answer (score 1):

What happens depends on the setting of `search_path`. PostgreSQL searches the existing schemas on `search_path` in turn, and as soon as it finds an index of that name, it drops the index and is done.

Answer (score 0):

> can I write DROP INDEX test.a.a_idx ?

The index is in the same schema as its table, so it would just be `DROP INDEX test.a_idx` (if you want/need to override search_path)